# ExecuteStoreQuery with "anonymous" table valued parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, relational-database

I am trying to execute `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery` with a table valued SQL parameter

```
var data = new DataTable();
data.Columns.Add("NAME1", typeof(int));
data.Columns.Add("NAME2", typeof(int));

... add rows to the data table

SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter()
{
    ParameterName = "@pairs",
    Value = data,
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured
};
ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<long>(
                "select ID" +
                "from TEST t join @pairs p " +
                "on t.NAME1 = p.NAME1 and t.NAME2= p.NAME2"
)
```

The execution terminates with this error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'The table type parameter '@pairs' must have a valid type name.'

which I understand I did not specify the type name because this is not an existing table type in the database. So, is there no way to pass the list of any non-primitive parameters to a query? or am I missing something?

Any alternate solutions using `ObjectSet/Queryable` instead of native query will be accepted.

Comment: Pretty sure there is not other way to do it other than create the table type in the database - any reason not to do that? Some people take the approach of creating comma-separated strings etc and then splitting them out - not recommended because it can lead to all sorts of issues - but can sometimes solve the current issue.

Comment: @DaleK no reason.. I can create one, it just seems unneccessary to me.. Since in SQL you could easily achieve this on the fly using a temporary table or `with` clause - without predefining a table. It's a bit surprising there is no functionality to generate that type of query. I believe it would be fairly easy to implement..